# Marshal DefaultListModel into xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I've looked at a few posts on this topic, but none of the solutions have worked for me.  I have a `DefaultListModel` called `partsListRight` that is a member of my window class, and I have an inner class called configuration that contains an `ArrayList` which I want to populate with the items in `partsListRight`:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Configuration{
    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<String> Component;


    public Configuration(){
        Component = new ArrayList<String>();
        Object[] partsList = partsListRight.toArray();
        for (Object object : partsList){
            Component.add((String)object);
        }
    }
}
```

In my window class I have a `save()` method that does the marshalling for the `ArrayList` Component:

```
public void save() {


    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    try{
    File file = new File("C:\\configuration.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(configuration, file);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(configuration, System.out);
    } catch(JAXBException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

However when I try to run this method I get the error that Configuration is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.  I'm not sure how to get around this.  Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Does it have to be non-static? Does it have to be an inner class at all?

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be an inner class, but it does have to be non-static, as the DefaultListModel depends on which items are selected in a JList in the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an inner class. I can see the reason you're doing it is because you want access to the the `DefaultListModel`, but it's unnecessary. You JAXB model classes shouldn't have to know anything about any gui aspects. It just simply meant to model.

That said, your design is a little off. You should instead just make `Configuration` its own class file. You don't need the constructor the `Configuration` class either. Just have a `getter` for the `List`, and populate it from the `save()` method. Something like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "component"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Configuration")
public class Configuration {

    protected List<String> component;

    public List<String> getComponent() {
        if (component == null) {
            component = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.component;
    }
}
```

Then when you actually want to do the marshalling, just create the `Configuration` class, and fill it with the list model elements.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
List<String> list = config.getComponent();
Object[] partsList = partsListRight.toArray();
for (Object object : partsList){
    list.add((String)object);
}

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
                      Configuration.class.getPackage().getName());
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Thanks for the reply; I tried using this and now I've got a new error. javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.cooksys.assessment" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index...

Sorry, I'm used to using xjc where you have an `ObjectFactory` created for you. In your case, just create the `JAXBContext` the same way you were before, with `Configuration.class`, instead of `Configuration.class.getPackage().getName();`

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
```

**Test**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Marshall {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        List<String> list = config.getComponent();
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration>
    <component>Hello</component>
    <component>World</component>
</Configuration>
```

**Note:** Would be the same using your current annotation configuration (Again, xjc create the above annotations :-)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Configuration")
public class Configuration {

    @XmlElement
    protected List<String> component;

    public List<String> getComponent() {
        if (component == null) {
            component = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.component;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I tried using this and now I've got a new error.  javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.cooksys.assessment" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.cooksys.assessment" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]

Unfortunately I really don't understand how this code is working, and I have no idea what this error means.